# Excluding second-stage covariates from first stage

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, two-step-estimation

I have a question about the inclusion/exclusion of certain covariates in a 2SLS model.  My concern is that my instrumental variable, Z, influences Y through two pathways: X1 and X2.  If I am interested in isolating the X1 effect, is it sufficient to include X2 in the second stage equation, but not the first?  Can this be done using the **fixest** package in R?

More generally, how can the inclusion of certain controls (and at what stage) help to block causal pathways in 2SLS models?

Thanks very much,
-Carl

Comment: Intuition says your model will not be identified. If you have two endogenous variables, you will need at least two instrumental variables. Here's a related [SE.econ post just for good measure](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/19330).

Comment: I'd say that arguably your variable just isn't an instrument if it affects the target variable in a way that's not via your variable of interest. What I'm not sure is which causal effect are you actually interested in?